# Best practice for HTML <option> : selected VS selected="selected"

Tags: html, html-select

What is the best practice to pre-select an `<option>` in a `<select>`?

According to different websites, both works. But which one is better? the most compatible?

```
<option selected="selected">Foo</option>
<option selected>Bar</option>
```

Comment: According to W3C, the syntax used is `<option selected>option 1</option>` (more at [W3C selected attribute page](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_selected.asp)).

Comment: @Zeratops that is not the W3C website... it is w3schools, a small difference...

Comment: @PatrickHofman You right, I linked this page because W3School rely on W3C statements in general.

Comment: @Zeratops I think a lot of users here think that w3schools is a bad source, since it is often wrong or incomplete.

Comment: @Zeratops I disagree. W3School is definitly not trustable. W3Schools keeps out of date information published, and in some cases publishes information that was never true.(see http://www.w3fools.com/)

Comment: I may have been _fooled_ by the name of W3School wbesite for sure ! I would like to change the link name on my first comment but the edition is locked. By the way, thank you for the link @4wk_.

Comment: Modern readers should note that w3fools.com now states: "When W3Fools was launched in 2011, the state of documentation for developers was poor. This site documented many content errors and issues with the W3Schools website. The Mozilla Developer Network was around but it did not have much support at the time. Today, W3Schools has largely resolved these issues and addressed the majority of the undersigned developers' concerns. For many beginners, W3Schools has structured tutorials and playgrounds that offer a decent learning experience."

Comment: @MarredCheese Yes, for a couple of years now W3School is a lot better that it used to be.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are writing XHTML, `selected="selected"` is required.

If you are writing HTML, `selected` is fewer keystrokes and fewer bytes.

Neither has better compatibility with browsers.

Comment: @JackNUMBER — If you write in *any* version of HTML that has `<option>` elements, you can use both. The only *objective* measures I can come up with say that `selected` is better.

Comment: @Quentin what if we don't use `selected="selected"` in XHTML? you mean it won't work?

Comment: @HumaAli — It will throw an XML parsing error and abort. (Assuming the document is being parsed as XHTML and not as HTML-with-errors).

Answer (score 3):

According to the [HTML4 standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-option-element), using `selected` implies it is `selected="selected"`. So the standard already defines both are supported. Their code sample already includes a code block just using `selected`.

For compatibility with XHTML (specifically XML is the 'problem' here), there is a `selected="selected"` option.

[HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-option-element) also defines `selected` on its own is valid, so no need to worry.