# HTML <option> : selected doesn't work in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, xhtml, html-select

I have following HTML Code for Select tag:

```
<select name="myList" id="myQues" defaultvalue="">

<option value="" selected="">Select Your Option</option>
<option value="BestFriendName">Your Best friends Name</option>
<option value="MothersName">Mothers Name</option>

</select>
```

problem is, it never selects my `option` which I have marked as `selected`. It shows **Your Best friends Name** option as `selected` instead of **Select Your Option**. This works fine in Chrome. What could be the possible reason? Is it something to do with `select = "selected"` vs `select = ""` otherwise I do not see anything wrong with my code.

**EDIT**

My HTML tag has `xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"`

Comment: Kindly check my answer , hopefully it will meet your expectations.

Comment: "My HTML tag has xmlnx = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"" — Why are you using XHTML? You misspelt `xmlns`. Use [a validator](http://validator.w3.org/).

Comment: @Quentin its legacy code written by someone else. Can't change that implementation. Do you also suggest that this could be due to XHTML? i.e I need to add `selected="selected"` to get it fixed instead of `selected=""`

Comment: "Do you also suggest that this could be due to XHTML?" — No.

Comment: You have no clue about this issue?

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. If I put your code in [a codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gjMyJE) (or in a xhtml file for that matter) it always shows "Select Your Option" as the default, no matter what browser I open it in. So the problem must be with code you're not showing here. Can you produce a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
<select name="myList" id="myQues" defaultvalue="">

<option value="" selected>Select Your Option</option>
<option value="BestFriendName ">Your Best friends Name</option>
<option value="MothersName">Mothers Name</option>

</select>
```

Comment: What is the difference between `selected=""` and `selected?`

Comment: @HumaAli Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31782817/best-practice-for-html-option-selected-vs-selected-selected It gives a good explenation.

Comment: Check Edited Question

Comment: In XHTML, attribute minimization is forbidden, and the selected attribute must be defined as <option selected="selected">. Can you try this?

Comment: @JelmerBouman — If that was the problem then the browser would render the yellow screen of death.

Comment: @Quentin interesting, never had a problem like that. Could you explain or send me a link with explanation?

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=xml+parse+error+browser&safe=off&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi_zML0n6PcAhVHAsAKHcefBCgQ_AUICygC&biw=1595&bih=938#imgrc=Y0GhkyNE3Ow8eM:

Answer (score -2):

Add `selected` attribute (tested in IE 11):

```html
<select name="myList" id="myQues" defaultvalue="">

<option value="" selected="" selected>Select Your Option</option>
<option value="BestFriendName">Your Best friends Name</option>
<option value="MothersName">Mothers Name</option>

</select>
```

Comment: What is the difference between `selected=""` and `selected`?

Comment: `selected` is a shortcut. _In XHTML, attribute minimization is forbidden, and the selected attribute must be defined as <option selected="selected">._ You can find out more here https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_selected.asp .

Comment: @HumaAli  For Simple Html You can use **selected** , But for XHTML You can use **selected="selected"** .

Comment: @David You mean to say, selected="selected" will work and selected = "" won't? Alos, why does it work fine in chrome?

Comment: @HumaAli literally these two are the standard Syntax. Beside this , i have never use selected = "" . Kindly have a look and let me know , to step up in knowledge . Thank You