# How to select the value of a combo box in the controller in Spring MVC with Thymeleaf?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have the following code for the view.

```
<input type="text" name="person" th:value="${person}">

<select name="gender" id="gender" th:value="${gender}">
    <option value="Male">Male</option>
    <option value="Female">Female</option>   
</select>
```

Controller

```
modelAndView.addObject("person", "Nancy");
modelAndView.addObject("gender", "Female");
```

When this runs, the person field correctly displays "Nancy".
But the combo box displays male instead of female.
How to make it show the correct value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use Thymeleaf to handle the `selected` attribute of each option, to ensure the initial display is correct:

```html
<select name="gender" id="gender" th:value="${gender}">
    <option value="Male" th:selected="${gender} == 'Male'">Male</option>
    <option value="Female" th:selected="${gender} == 'Female'">Female</option>   
</select>
```

This generates the following HTML:

```html
<select name="gender" id="gender" value="Female">
    <option value="Male">Male</option>
    <option value="Female" selected="selected">Female</option>   
</select>
```

The `selected` attribute is an HTML boolean attribute - Thymeleaf documentation for these is [here](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#fixed-value-boolean-attributes).

Comment: perfect. It worked. Thank you. Answer accepted. Just a question. What it means selected="selected"? I was just aware of selected by itself. Like in ```<option value="Female" selected>Female</option>```

Comment: Thank you. You are absolutely correct about `selected` (and all the other booleans in HTML). As described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31782817/best-practice-for-html-option-selected-vs-selected-selected), it's the difference between XHTML documents (where you must use `selected="selected"`) and HTML5 documents (where you can choose to use just `selected` - but the other notation is also valid).

Comment: Having said that, Thymeleaf appears to always use the XHTML style: _"if evaluated to true, the attribute will be set to its fixed value, and if evaluated to false, the attribute will not be set"_, where "_set to its fixed value_" means `foo="foo"`.